# Exclude Rows based on overlapping restrictions (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was looking at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823353/exclude-rows-based-on-other-rows-sql), but was still having trouble creating my statement. I have the following query

```
SELECT SUM(AMT) AS TOTAL, NAME, YEAR 
FROM TABLE WHERE IND='ISVALID' GROUP BY NAME, YEAR
```

I would get the following results

```
TOTAL | NAME | YEAR 
====================
10000 | JOHN | 2010  
20500 | PETE | 2009 
12500 | MIKE | 2008 
50500 | MARY | 2008 
50500 | MARY | 2007 
40000 | JANE | 2007
```

I would like to exclude 50500 | MARY | 2008, which has an IND column with 'ISVALID' as well. How do I do this?

Comment: What criteria are you using to exclude records?

Comment: @simchona - The criteria is an indicator which returns all that data, but 50500 mary 2008 is a false positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(AMT) AS TOTAL, NAME, YEAR 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE IND='ISVALID' AND (NAME <> 'MARY' OR YEAR <> 2008)
GROUP BY NAME, YEAR
```